# iTextSharp parse HTML to 508 compliant PDF table

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, itext, section508

The code below will create a PDF from HTML.  The problem is that when the document is tagged the TH tags are written to the PDF as a TD.  Is there anyway to get the tags in the PDF to appear as TH?

```
          string html = @"<table>
                            <tr>
                                <TH> header1 </TH>
                                <TH> header2 </TH>
                                <TH> header3 </TH>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td> col 1</td>
                                <td> col 2</td>
                                <td> col 3</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>";

        FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\\test.pdf", FileMode.Create);
        TextReader reader = new StringReader(html);

        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 30, 30, 30, 30);

        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs);
        writer.SetTagged();

        writer.SetPdfVersion(PdfWriter.PDF_VERSION_1_7);

        document.Open();


        XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, document, reader);
        document.Close();

        fs.Close();`
```

Comment: Try putting the first `<TR>` in a `<THEAD>` element, and the other `<TR>` in a `<TBODY>` element, like http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_thead.asp

Comment: I just tried that with no luck, the iTextSharp method ParseXHtml did not even recognize the tag and as a result it was not even added to the PDF

Comment: I created a ticket on the issue tracker for paying customers so that somebody can take a look. If you have an account on the issue tracker, please let me know so that I can add you as a Watcher to this ticket so that you are kept informed about the progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have added a correct tagging of TH element. The changes will be included into the next iText XMLWorker release.
Generally XMLWorker is not adopted to generate correctly tagged PDF. But XMLWorker uses a base iText Core tagging logic and TD is default role for all kind of table cells.

Answer (score 0):

The functionality you want is not supported in the release you are using.

Please take a look at [today's update of the `TableData` class in XML Worker](http://sourceforge.net/p/itext/xmlworker/ci/2113a1933e7d5ba7a28a822be8d7dde3f3b28efb):

```
@@ -97,6 +99,10 @@
                 if (direction != PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_DEFAULT) {
                     cell.setRunDirection(direction);
                 }
+
+        if (HTML.Tag.TH.equalsIgnoreCase(tag.getName())) {
+            cell.setRole(PdfName.TH);
+        }
         try {
             HtmlPipelineContext htmlPipelineContext = getHtmlPipelineContext(ctx);
             cell = (HtmlCell) getCssAppliers().apply(cell, tag, htmlPipelineContext);
```

This fixes your problem in iText. It is now scheduled for porting to iTextSharp. The fix will be in the next release.